# History of commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, history

Is there any way to find which commands have been executed between 2 specific dates (like 2 to 3 months period)?

I can use the history command, but I have powered the system on/off.

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: What commands are you talking about? What is the history command? The one in Bash doesn't care whether you've powered anything on or off.

Comment: what ever commands i executed on terminals

Comment: History command -http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdln_history.htm

Comment: Are you using Bash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not by default. You should install the psacct (Process Accounting) utilities to get this functionality.

> sudo apt-get install acct

The ubuntu package turns on process accounting as part of the install. It provides the following commands:

- ac - print statistics about users’ connect time
- lastcomm - print out information about previously executed commands.
- sa - summarizes accounting information
- accton -  turns process accounting on or off

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible with the default install.  If you care about the next 2 - 3 months, it is possible to set something up to track this, but not for the prior 2-3 months.

Comment: is there any other way to track on now ?