# Does Linux save the history of executed commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, command-history

I know we can do a "history" command or use control+R to find the command history in a particular shell session. But is there a way to find out the command history of my last ssh session for example?

I am also curious to know where (in the system) linux saves the command line history, even if it is just for the current shell session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your history is logged by your shell. Bash, for example, uses the file `~/.bash_history` by default. It is also not limited by your current session, but the history is usually persisted beyond that, up to what the environment variables `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` allow.

More information on how the history works in `bash` is available in it's man page, in the section titled `HISTORY`.

---

For more thorough recording of command history, you can use process accounting, as explained in [answers to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/25726/history-of-commands).